# alert not showing after form validation success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get a console log message if my validation passes but in its current state it doesn't do anything. All the validation errors display as expected but if there are no errors the success console log message doesn't display.

```
    $.ajax({
                url:'php/functions.php',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                data: {name: name, email: email, venue: venue, guests: guests, comments: comments},
                })

            .done(function(data) {

                console.log(data);

                if(!data.success) {

                    $( "#submit" ).prop('disabled', false);

                    if(data.errors.name) {
                        $( "#error-name" ).empty().append(data.errors.name).fadeIn();
                    }

                    if(data.errors.email) {
                        $("#error-email").empty().append(data.errors.email).fadeIn();
                    }

                    if(data.errors.venue) {
                        $( "#error-venue" ).empty().append(data.errors.venue).fadeIn();
                    }

                    if(data.errors.guests) {
                        $( "#error-guests" ).empty().append(data.errors.guests).fadeIn();
                    }

                    if(data.errors.comments) {
                        $( "#error-comments" ).empty().append(data.errors.comments).fadeIn();
                    }

                } else {

                    alert("okay!");
                }
            })

            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            });
```

Comment: your log message is not showing up or your alert is not showing up?

Comment: the alert("okay!"); isn't showing but the console.log(data) is

Comment: do a console.log(data.success) after console.log(data) and see if it is actually set to true

Comment: Hmm. I get "undefined"

Comment: But doing this `console.log(data.message);` shows "success" in console

Comment: so that is you problem... check your functions.php to see what is set when there are no errors

Comment: `if($errors) {
  
  $response['success'] = false;
  $response['message'] = "Fail";
  
 } else {
  
  $reponse['success'] = true;
  $response['message'] = "Success!";
 }
 
 echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: then your if condition should change to if(!data.message) instead of if(!data.success)

Comment: If I do as you suggested, then I get the success message even when there should be validation errors

Comment: sorry I didn't see your code before commenting... yes,it should be (data.success), not sure why it comes out to be undefined though

Comment: yeah, I'm stumped. `console.log(data.success);` gives me undefined in console

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I had $reponse in my php instead of $response! console now returns "true" but still doesn't alert the success message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148548/discussion-between-jonathan-and-karthik-ganesan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said

> $reponse['success']

should be `

> $response['success']

also as per our chat, you could end up doing the same functionality with just the errors array rather than adding multiple properties to verify the same

if you stick with your code 
you can use either

> if(!data.success) { as done now

or you can use

> if(data.errors.length > 0) { }

in case of such issues always try to use `console.log()` to verify if your data or code is being executed.